# Book in which a young girl hides her findings about makeup and technology

Tags: story-identification, novel

This book was about a woman who lived in a small village with lots of children and woman. The village was run by a "boss" lady who tells them what they can and cannot do.

Later the woman went to her secret place and finds lipstick and tries it on even though it's banned, along with other things. The banned technology is from our current day, so they seem to be in the future.

I can't remember the rest of the plot, but it's been 3 or 4 years.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a novel? Movie? Something else?

Comment: It was just a book and only one at the time time , their was no movie for it at the time either which kinda sucks because I think it would have made a good one